# Is it possible to send push notifications from an ASP.NET MVC4 form to windows azure mobile services

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm trying to get windows azure mobile services to work, and now I want to let an administrator send his own custom push messages to all different devices.

Our idea is to make a website with login of course, where the administrator can fill in a form. This form will be sent or post to `windows azure mobile services` and then windows azure does the rest. Can someone point me in the right direction for sending to windows mobile azure from within asp.net MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's totally possible. You just need to create a notification Hub (service bus) to deliver your messages. Here some links:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-notification-hubs/
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/notification-hubs/getting-started-windows-dotnet/
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Service-Bus-Tutorials/Notifications-Hubs-with-iOS

Comment: Good solution! But its too expensive! Do we have an alternate one?

Comment: @FaizanMubasher you can use 3rd part solutions (i.e PubNub.com).